# Previous date is inserted on mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a class with a `DateTime` field.

```
Class aClass 
{
    [BsonId]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("dateCreated")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

But when I insert an bject in mongo via c# driver with a date let's say `DateCreated = new DateTime(2013, 12, 08)` the previous date is inserted.

```
> db.col.find();
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "dateCreated" :  ISODate("2013-12-07T22:00:00Z")
}
```

I am using `MongoDb 2.2.6`.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of MongoDB you are using.

Comment: @Ajai I added the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB stores all `DateTime` values as UTC time ([BSON Date type is the UTC datetime](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/)). That's why you see UTC time in database (your local time zone has two hours offset to UTC time). If you'll save UTC time, it will be stored as is. Check:

```
DateCreated = new DateTime(2013, 12, 8, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
```

When you are reading this values from database, they also will be have UTC time (value will be `12/7/2013 22:00:00` and if you'll check `Kind` property of date, it will be `Utc`). But you can ask Mongo to deserialize date into your local time zone date by applying `BsonDateTimeOptions` attribute:

```
[BsonElement("dateCreated")]
[BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

Now same date will be deserialized as Local and it will have value `12/8/2013 00:00:00`. You can enable same behavior to all `DateTime` values deserialization by setting default serialization options:

```
DateTimeSerializationOptions.Defaults = 
   DateTimeSerializationOptions.LocalInstance;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.

Comment: Would you prefer to keep date time conversion out of the domain? I think personally domain model is cleaner like this.